# jQuery - How to change variable in calculation with if statement

Tags: jquery, variables, if-statement

Here's my code:

```
function multiply() {
    var area = parseFloat($('#rugarea').val());

    var material = parseFloat($('#material').val())+parseFloat($('#intec').val());

    var clkit = parseFloat($('#clkit').val());

    var width = parseFloat($('#width').val()) || 0;

    var rugmiddle = (area * material);

    var rugsmall = ((area * material)*1.25);

  var rugsub = $('#rugtotal').text('£'+ (rugmiddle+clkit));
}
```

I need the calculation in `rugsub` to change the variable `rugmiddle` to `rugsmall` IF the variable `width` is < "2".  Now I've tried quite a few different ways of getting the result I need, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `var rugsub = $('#rugtotal').text('£'+ (rugmiddle < 2 ? rugsmall: rugmiddle +clkit));` is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need the calculation in `rugsub` to change the variable `rugmiddle` to
>   `rugsmall` IF the variable `width` is < "2".

If I understand this correctly you want the `total` to be `rugsmall + clkit` when `width < 2` otherwise `rugmiddle + clkit`.

If that is so, then this should do the trick:

```
// inspect width and if less than 2 use rugsmall otherwise use rugmiddle
var rug = width < 2 ? rugsmall : rugmiddle;

// calculate the total with the correct value
var rugTotal = rug + clkit;

// assign the total
var rugsub = $('#rugtotal').text('£' + rugTotal);
```

The full code could look like this:

```
function multiply() {
    var area = parseFloat($('#rugarea').val());
    var material = parseFloat($('#material').val()) + parseFloat($('#intec').val());
    var clkit = parseFloat($('#clkit').val());
    var width = parseFloat($('#width').val()) || 0;
    var rugmiddle = (area * material);
    var rugsmall = ((area * material) * 1.25);

    var rug = width < 2 ? rugsmall : rugmiddle;
    var rugTotal = rug + clkit;

    var rugsub = $('#rugtotal').text('£' + rugTotal);
}
```

You can write this in a single line but I leave the implementation detail to yourself.